# How to get DateSeparator in C

Tags: c, date, format, separator

I wish to get the date separator accordingly to the system's format's settings.
In *Delphi* I'm using `System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings.DateSeparator`, is there something like this in *C*?

Answer (score 3):

The C language and standard library do not provide any such information. This information can be obtained from whatever system you are targeting. How you do that is dependent on which system you target.

Comment: That's a different question. In Windows you'd use `GetLocaleInfoEx`. On Linux you'd use the POSIX functions, as harald says.

Comment: No. You asked to do it in C. And here that means the standardised language and its libraries.

Comment: I'm trying to explain to you what it means on this site to ask if something is possible in C. That's all. The question still asks for a pure C answer.  I have a feeling you don't fully grasp all the ins and outs of this site. How about looking at the UDF question?

Comment: Just two questions. One for Windows, one for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

> The C language and standard library do not provide any such
>   information. This information can be obtained from whatever system you
>   are targeting.

---

> Thanks for clarification, targets could be both linux and windows. In those cases, how to do what I asked?

You need different functions for different OS.

e.g.

```
GetDataSeparator()
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    Here goes implementation for Windows
#else
    May be more preprocessor commands and implementations for Linux/Mac
#endif
}
```

---

Not sure if I understood everything correctly.

For Windows you can parse values found in `HKCU\Control Panel\International`. For Linux [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/) might be helpful.

Comment: Don't hack the registry. Use the API.

Comment: Registry just a suggestion, don't know actual API.

Comment: It's a very poor suggestion. Don't do it.

Comment: Code in the "else" is always executed (Testing on Windows 64bit). Is the suggested ifdef condition correct?

Comment: Not so much executed as compiled. The #ifdef is evaluated by the preprocessor. Clearly `_WIN` is not defined which is not surprising. It's not a known conditional.

Comment: @ST3: Please, update your message using _WIN32 conditional

Comment: @ST3: In any case, as David said, ifdef is evaluated by the preprocessor. How to get if code is executing on windows?

Comment: @ExDev, oh sorry. It should be _WIN32, not a _WIN. That definition is made by compilers if they are compiling for Windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true as stated by the other answers that the C standard does not provide this information, posix does. So on any posix compliant system you can use the [`nl_langinfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nl_langinfo.3.html) api to get locale information.

You will not get the date separator though, but the date format that can be used by `strftime` to display the correctly formatted date for the locale. You can always parse this to get the date separator if that's what you really need, but for most uses the actual date format will probably be more useful.

Posix support for Windows is flakey, so you probably have to treat it differently, but for pretty much any other platform this should help you.